# How to position a System.Drawing shape object in the center of a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am simply trying to draw a rectangle in the center of a windows form but when I plot the shape at the center co-ordinates of the form and translate to account for the origin being in the top left corner, it is still not centered. The code:

```
namespace form_art
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;

            var rectangle = new Rectangle(250-100, 250-100, 200, 200);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Aqua, rectangle);

        }
    }
}
```

The form's dimensions are 500 by 500 pixels. So I plotted the rectangle at x:250, y:250 and then subtracted half of the height and width of the rectangle to account for where the origin is placed.
[image]

Comment: Use the ClientRectangle dimensions.

Comment: And when you use `ClientRectangle` or `ClientSize`, don't get its width and height values and hardcode them like what you're doing now. Instead, use `this.ClientSize.Width` and `this.ClientSize.Height`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I only hardcoded to show this example. This is not my actual project. Am I using Client Rectangle correctly(/this returns the same result)? var rectangle = new Rectangle((ClientRectangle.Height / 2) - 50, (ClientRectangle.Width / 2) - 50, 100, 100);

Comment: Because you have the width and height swapped out. In the Rectangle constructor parameters, `x` should rely on the width and `y` should rely on the height.

Answer (score 0):

Like @41686d6564 said, if you want to draw a shape in the middle of a panel or form, use **ClientSize.Width** and **ClientSize.Height**.
An example is

```
formGraphics.DrawRectangle(MyPen, 
new Rectangle((this.ClientSize.Width/2)-(x/2), (this.ClientSize.Height/2)-(y/2), x, y));
```